# How to increase size of object upwards and maintain its shape?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have the [following](http://jsfiddle.net/n484qzka/47/) CSS:

```
.tank {
    position:relative;
    width:12px;
    height:18px;
    background-color:#444;
}
.tank:before {
    width: 12px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color:#666;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px / 2.5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px / 2.5px;
    border-radius: 6px / 2.5px;
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
    top:-2.5px;
}
.tank:after {
    width: 12px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color:#444;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px / 2.5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px / 2.5px;
    border-radius: 6px / 2.5px;
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
    top:15.5px;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    z-index: -1;
}

 
 </style>
```

when I add it to my map it produces the following:

[image]

when I try to increase the size via the CSS the size is adjusted backwards (it goes downward not upwards).

[image]

I tried to fix it via the position and the `height` but still get the same down result.

**Questions:**

1. How can I have it adjusted upwards
2. Maintain the cylinder in the same shape (the base and the `top` should be rounded).
3. Is it possible to have a 'dynamic adjustment' say  `<div class="tank-20"></div>` (means 20 `height`) and  `<div class="tank-80"></div>` (= 80 in `height`).

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n484qzka/47/)

Comment: 1) Regarding using CSS to adjust the size 'upwards': If you intend to increase the numerical value and expect it to rise to the top, you would probably have to transform the tank 180degrees.

2) To keep the shape and the ratio of curves&lines intact, you can also try implementing this thing using SVG

3) You can have dynamic adjustment, that would mean having to use Javascript

Comment: @viditkothari use my jsfiddle - see if it works. (it doesnt)

Comment: true, it doesn't

Comment: It grows downward because your positioning specifies an explicit `top` value. If you positioned it using `bottom` instead, height increases would grow upward. Another option would be to use [transform: scaleY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) to scale it up with the [transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) at the bottom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can update your code like below:

```css
.tank {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block; /* this will make them stay at the bottom */
  margin: 40px 10px;
  width: 120px;
  height: var(--w,180px);
  background-color: #444;
  border-radius: 60px / 25px;
}

.tank:before,
.tank:after{ 
  border-radius: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width:100%;
  height: 50px;
}
.tank:before {
  background-color: #666;
  top: 0;
}

.tank:after {
  background-color: #444;
  bottom:0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="tank"></div>
<div class="tank" style="--w:100px"></div>
<div class="tank" style="--w:200px"></div>
<div class="tank" style="--w:80px"></div>
```

Another idea. Hover to see the growing effect:

```css
.tank {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
  margin: 40px 10px;
  width: 120px;
  /* big height here to illustarte, 
    you don't need it if you will place your element using position:absolute */
  height: 300px; 
}

.tank:before,
.tank:after{ 
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width:100%;
  height: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 60px / 25px;
}
.tank:after {
  background: 
    radial-gradient(50% 50%,#666 98%,transparent 100%) top/100% 50px no-repeat, 
    #444;
  bottom:25px;
  height:var(--w,180px);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  transition:0.5s;
}

.tank:before {
  background-color: #444;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.tank:hover::after {
  height:calc(1.5*var(--w,180px));
}
```

```html
<div class="tank"></div>
<div class="tank" style="--w:100px"></div>
<div class="tank" style="--w:200px"></div>
<div class="tank" style="--w:80px"></div>
```

Comment: A+ thank you. Got it. As aside question, what if I wanted also to change the background-color via the style. How would you send another parameter? e.g., style="--w:100px & background-color=#444" ? Thanks again!

Comment: @ProcolHarum  `style="--w:100px;--c:red"`

Comment: and the actult css would be: background-color: *var (--c) ?

Answer (score 2):

When you increase the `height` of the `.tank` you should increase the `top` property at `.tank:after` as well due to that you can not increase the height `.tank` and the size add upwards of the `.tank` the only solution to that is use `right`, `left`, `top` and `bottom` to adjust where your `.tank` should be just see an example on how I increased the `height` of the `.tank` an still have the cylinder shape

> I increase `height` of `.tank` from `180px` to `225px`

> and top of `.tank:after` from `155px` to `200px`

### Example

```css
.tank {
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 225px;
  background-color: #444;
}

.tank:before {
  width: 120px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #666;
  -moz-border-radius: 60px / 25px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 60px / 25px;
  border-radius: 60px / 25px;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: -25px;
}

.tank:after {
  width: 120px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #444;
  -moz-border-radius: 60px / 25px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 60px / 25px;
  border-radius: 60px / 25px;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="tank"></div>
```